# Select query (one table)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table Pruza in my database and situation in that table is for example:

```
SifVU     Name
1         Test1
2         Test2
1         Test3
2         Test3
```

How to make Select query which returns only Test3 as a result because only Test3 have both Sif's (1 and 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it only shows names that have SifVU 1 and 2:

```
select one.name
from (select name from Pruza where SifVU = 1) one
join (select name from Pruza where SifVU = 2) two
on (one.name = two.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name
FROM Pruza
WHERE SifVU in (1,2)
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SifVU) = 2
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8795/5).

Answer (score 0):

This can be used for any number of TEST3 type of records and no need of any hard coding

```
SELECT B.NAME
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(SifVU) AS CNT_SifVU FROM TABLE GROUP BY SifVU) AS A
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS DISTINCT_SIFVU, NAME
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT SifVU, Name FROM TABLE) AS B
) AS C
ON B.DISTINCT_SIFVU = A.CNT_SifVU
```